# how to loop through files that match a regular expression in a unix shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

I want to be able to loop through a list of files that match a particular pattern. I can get unix to list these files using ls and egrep with a regular expression, but I cannot find a way to turn this into an iterative process. I suspect that using ls is not the answer. Any help would be gratefully received.

My current ls command looks as follows:

```
ls | egrep -i 'MYFILE[0-9][0-9]([0][1-9]|1[0-2])([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01]).dat'
```

I would expect the above to match:

- MYFILE160418.dat
- myFILE170312.DAT
- MyFiLe160416.DaT

but not:

- MYOTHERFILE150202.DAT
- Myfile.dat
- myfile.csv

Thanks,

Paul.

Comment: Hi @paul-frith, you should start with a `while`or a `for`. Use a counter as in the example -> http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: In many cases, you do not need an explicit loop, since you can pass the arguments to another program via pipe, possibly using `xargs`.

Comment: Brilliant thank you - I hadn't realised you could use ls in a for loop.

Comment: Try: `ls | egrep -i 'MYFILE\d{6}\.dat'`

Comment: Saleem, Whilst neater, I believe this would give looser matching criteria, using your method would allow for month of greater than 12 and day of greater than 31.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use (GNU) `find` with the regex search option instead of parsing `ls`.

```
find . -regextype "egrep" \
       -iregex '.*/MYFILE[0-9][0-9]([0][1-9]|1[0-2])([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01]).dat' \
       -exec [[whatever you want to do]] {} \;
```

Where `[[whatever you want to do]]` is the command you want to perform on the names of the files.

From the man page

> ```
> -regextype type
>           Changes  the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex tests 
>           which occur later on the command line.  Currently-implemented types are 
>           emacs (this is the default),posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-egrep and 
>           posix-extended.
>
>   -regex pattern
>           File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole 
>           path, not a search.  For example, to match a file named `./fubar3', you can 
>           use the regular expression
>           `.*bar.' or `.*b.*3', but not `f.*r3'.  The regular expressions understood by 
>           find are by default Emacs Regular Expressions, but this can be changed with 
>           the -regextype option.
>
>   -iregex pattern
>           Like -regex, but the match is case insensitive.
> ```

Comment: Interesting - funnily enough "find" was what I looked to in the first place, but I couldn't get my regex to work. -regextype "egrep" is what I needed!

Answer (score 8):

Based on the link Andy K provided I have used the following to loop based on my matching criteria:

```
for i in $(ls | egrep -i 'MYFILE[0-9][0-9]([0][1-9]|1[0-2])([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01]).dat' ); do             
 echo item: $i;         
done
```

Comment: I've looked at this and it seems that parsing ls is a bad idea due to UNIX allowing almost any character in a file name, including newline feeds etc. However given that I am regex matching, surely that problem is mitigated in this instance. Are there other reasons to not parse an ls?

Comment: Do not use `ls` output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct: 
                `for file in *.txt`. Read [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)